# how to change other spinner based on the spinner selected before?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

i'm trying to change my second spinner based on what i choose in the first spinner without using any json or database. it must be change the spinner below depend on what we choose in the first spinner. i'm trying with the code below but is doesn't work

**this is the java code**

```
    Spinner gedungSpn, lantaiSpn, ruangSpn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kelas);
GedungSpinner();

        if (gedungSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
            LantaiSpinnerRektorat();
        }else if(gedungSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1){
            LantaiSpinnerGL();
        }
    }
 public void GedungSpinner(){

        gedungSpn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gedung_spn);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Rektorat");
        list.add("Griya Legita");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gedungSpn.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void LantaiSpinnerRektorat(){

        lantaiSpn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lantai_spn);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Lantai 1");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        lantaiSpn.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void LantaiSpinnerGL(){

        lantaiSpn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lantai_spn);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Lantai 1");
        list.add("Lantai 2");
        list.add("Lantai 3");
        list.add("Lantai 4");
        list.add("Lantai 5");
        list.add("Lantai 6");
        list.add("Lantai 7");
        list.add("Lantai 8");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        lantaiSpn.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

please help me. maybe some trick could help. i'm also trying that change the adapter on if statement but it still doesnt work at all

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?And one more thing you are not changing the index of any of the secondary spinner,as both are having the same value in the first index you may think it is not changing but where it is changing in reality.

Comment: i'm not getting any exception. it just don't want to become LantaiSpinnerGL(); when i select Griya Legita in the first spinner

Comment: Expand the second spinner and see how many values are there.
Also just debug once and see it is executing the `if` OR `elseIf` .

Comment: Also I see you haven't added any selectedIndexChange listener with your first spinner.This is mandatory otherwise it wont work.

Comment: how do I add selectedIndexChange?

Comment: See the answer below.If works please upvote.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
        if (gedungSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
            LantaiSpinnerRektorat();
        }else if(gedungSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1){
            LantaiSpinnerGL();
        }
```

with

```
gedungSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0){
                   LantaiSpinnerRektorat();
                 }else if(position == 1){
                   LantaiSpinnerGL();
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```